# check if a numpy array is a numpy masked array

Tags: numpy

As output of a script, I have `numpy masked array` and standard `numpy array`. How do I easily check while running the script if an array is a masked (has `data`, `mask` attributes) one or not?

Comment: `numpy.ma.is_masked`

Comment: `np.ma.is_masked` tests whether it has masked values; not quite the same as the `np.ma.isMaskedArray` function.

Answer (score 8):

You can check explicitly if it is a masked array by `isinstance(arr, np.ma.MaskedArray)`, or you can check for the attributes `hasattr(arr, 'mask')`. I'd probably recommend the first approach in general.

Comment: `np.ma.isMaskedArray(arr)` uses the `isinstance` approach.